# i want my Android mobile to become my server

Tags: android

i want my Android mobile to become my server ? can anybody guide me ?? 
work on a simple HTML Pages display , just like displaying page

x.html 

hello world

Comment: Serving what, to whom, for what purpose, and why android?  Your question is lacking sufficient detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project for this called [i-jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/).  It's a port of the [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) web server.

Comment: hi u are the champion of this hour